# How do I write number pyramid in python without using range function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I have to write a code in python to show the following output:
1
1  2  1
1  2  3  2  1
1  2  1
1
in a rhombus shape. But I can't use range function in the code.

I have written the following code using range:

```
rows = 4
for i in range(rows+1):
    s=0
    for k in range(rows-i):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range(i+1):
        s=s+10**(i-j)
    print(s*s)
    print(" ")
for i in range(rows-1,-1,-1):
    s=0
    for k in range(rows-i):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in range(i+1):
        s=s+10**(i-j)
    print(s*s)
    print(" ")
```

Please help me out on how to write the code without using range function.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `range` or `not_range` :P

`not_range` returns a `list` from `a` to `b`

Not using inbuilt `range` anywhere!

```
def not_range(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return [a]+not_range(a+1,b)
    elif a>b:
        return [a]+not_range(a-1,b)
    else:
        return []

rows = 4
for i in not_range(0,rows+1):
    s=0
    for k in not_range(0,rows-i):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in not_range(0,i+1):
        s=s+10**(i-j)
    print(s*s)
    print(" ")
for i in not_range(rows-1,-1):
    s=0
    for k in not_range(0,rows-i):
        print(end=" ")
    for j in not_range(0,i+1):
        s=s+10**(i-j)
    print(s*s)
    print(" ")
```

```
    1
 
   121
 
  12321
 
 1234321
 
123454321
 
 1234321
 
  12321
 
   121
 
    1
```